# How to copy and replace a file for all user profiles with Admin rights

Tags: c#, windows, authentication, active-directory, gpo

I have researched all the articles here and on Google. While some seem to be what I need I continue to run into this problem. I could certainly use some assistance getting this resolved once and for all.

I want to copy a Customize.xml file from the server and have it replace the current file in all user profiles. I would prefer to make this so that it will run for anyone that logs on each time. Any assistance figuring this out and getting it to work would be greatly appreciated.

[image: System.UnauthorizedAccessException]

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;

namespace copy_delete_move_files
{
    public class SimpleFileCopy
    {
        public static object Logger { get; private set; }

        static void Main()
        {

            string fileName = "Customize.xml";
            string sourcePath = @"\\serverpath\c$\TestFolder";
            string targetPath = @"\\desktoppath\c$\%USERPROFILE%\APPDATA\Roaming\Litera\Customize";

            // Use Path class to manipulate file and directory paths.
            string sourceFile = Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName);

            string destFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);

            // To copy a folder's contents to a new location:
            // Create a new target folder, if necessary.
            if (!Directory.Exists(targetPath))


            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(targetPath);
            }

            // To copy a file to another location and 
            // overwrite the destination file if it already exists.
            File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);

            // To copy all the files in one directory to another directory.
            // Get the files in the source folder.
            // Note: Check for target path was performed previously
            // in this code example.

            if (Directory.Exists(sourcePath))
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);

                // Copy the files and overwrite destination files if they already exist.
                foreach (string s in files)
                {
                    // Use static Path methods to extract only the file name from the path.
                    fileName = Path.GetFileName(s);
                    destFile = Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
                    File.Copy(s, destFile, true);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Source path does not exist!");
            }

            // Keep console window open in debug mode.
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Just to clarify. 
Would this code run when the user logs in? And would it run under their account? Who has access to those files?

Comment: @Crick3t. Ideally it would run every time the user logs in, for every user.

Comment: I think the code is not bad. You need to make sure it runs under a user who has access to those files. Probably the best is to create a GPO rule.

Comment: @Crick3t I finally got it to work. We already have this being pushed out by SCCM as a scheduled task  with a script but I was trying to make it work from C#. Because it is already running it was interfering. I changed the path and everything worked like a charm.

Comment: While looking at why it wasn't creating the Customize folder with the xml file copied into it I found that c$\%USERPROFILE% part of c$\%USERPROFILE%\APPDATA\Roaming\Litera\Customize is the folder that is being created. I want the Customize folder created in the Litera directory. How do I make this work?